# Writing a flow libdef for an HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, static-typing, flow-typed

I'm writing a library definition for a library that gives us an HOC. The implementation of the HOC looks like this:

```
const withValidation = TargetComponent => class extends React.Component {
  onSubmit: () => { ... }
  getFormData: () => { ... }
  getErrors: () => { ... }
  setField: diff => { ... }
  resetState: () => { ... }
  render () { return <TargetComponent ... /> }
}
```

I want to write a library definition that specifies that the component returned 
from the HOC has the instance methods listed above. Due to the way this component works, it's accessed via a ref, which is where I would like these to show up.

I've tried writing a libdef for the returned component - here is the relevant parts of that:

```
declare class WithValidation<FormConfig> extends React$Component {
  onSubmit: () => boolean;
  getFormData: () => {
    [key: string]: string,
  };
  setField: (diff: {}) => void;
  getErrors: () => { [key: string]: string | null };
  resetState: () => void;
}
```

This gives me some errors indicating that my wrapped components are *not* React components. Obviously i'm doing something wrong with the way I specify the class - but I can't figure out what I should write instead.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Flow implemented `React.AbstractComponent` in 0.89.0 to help with writing HOCs. Check out the [documentation for writing HOCs](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/hoc/#hocs-as-of-0890-).

Comment: Hi - and welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Thanks for the suggestion! Could you elaborate on you could use `React.AbstractComponent` to type this kind of HOC? A more detailed answer would be more helpful for people coming to this question at a later point in time :)